# Core Data add item if it doesn't exist already

Tags: ios, web-services

I have a webservice that will send data down to the phone. Sometimes it will already exist as a core data object and sometimes it will be new. I have a unique reference for the item so I basically want to search to see if the object exists and if not then it saves it to the core data storage. If it exists then in an ideal world I want to update the object.

At the moment I remove all objects and fill them again from my webservice, but obviously this isn't practical when there are lots of items.

Comment: You have described the answer there. Is there a specific problem you are having implementing it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should have something like an unique ID in you Entity. Then you fetch entity with that ID from Core Data if it's empty you create a new one, otherwise you use fetched one. So what's the problem with that? If you use concurrency that may be harder.

Comment: I was thinking if everytime I do a sync I have to do a separate fetch request that it would be quite memory intensive. If that's the best way to go about it then I guess that would work ok.

Comment: I may have to cater for concurrent access, although it's not clear at the moment if it's going to be a problem or not within the app.

Comment: If you create the "lookup" fetch request once, keep reference to it for the time of syncing and only modify the predicate to see if the object already exists, the performance should be absolutely fine, assuming you do this heavy lifting on the back-end thread.